# Pandas read_csv without knowing whether header is present

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have an input file with known columns, let's say two columns `Name` and `Sex`. Sometimes it has the header line `Name,Sex`, and sometimes it doesn't:

**1.csv**:

```
Name,Sex
John,M
Leslie,F
```

**2.csv**:

```
John,M
Leslie,F
```

Knowing the identity of the columns beforehand, is there a nice way to handle both cases with the same `read_csv` command? Basically, I want to specify `names=['Name', 'Sex']` and then have it infer `header=0` only when the header is there. Best I can come up with is:

- 1) Read the first line of the file before doing `read_csv`, and set
  parameters appropriately.
- 2) Just do `df = pd.read_csv(input_file, names=['Name', 'Sex'])`,
  then check whether the zeroeth row is identical to the header, and if
  so drop it (and then maybe have to renumber the rows).

But this doesn't seem like that unusual of a use case to me. Is there a built-in way of doing this with `read_csv` that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

using new feature - [selection by callable](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-callable):

```
cols = ['Name','Sex']

df = (pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=cols)
      [lambda x: np.ones(len(x)).astype(bool)
                 if (x.iloc[0] != cols).all()
                 else np.concatenate([[False], np.ones(len(x)-1).astype(bool)])]
)
```

using [.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
df = (pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=cols)
        .query('Name != "Name" and Sex != "Sex"'))
```

i'm not sure that this is the most elegant way, but this should work as well:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=cols)

if (df.iloc[0] == cols).all():
    df = df[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for all the options! The last version still looks cleanest to me, so I guess I'll use that approach. I'll leave the question open for now and accept in a couple days if nothing else comes up.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer, for me I had to set index_col=False in read_csv in order to get the first row to align if there is a header.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a way of detecting the header without prior knowledge of its names:

```py
if any(df.iloc[0].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))):
    df = df[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

And by changing it slightly, it can update the current header with the detected one:

```py
if any(df.iloc[0].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))):
    df = df[1:].reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns=df.iloc[0])
```

This would allow easily selecting the desired behavior:

```py
update_header = True

if any(df.iloc[0].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))):
    new_header = df.iloc[0]

    df = df[1:].reset_index(drop=True)

    if update_header:
        df.rename(columns=new_header, inplace=True)
```

**Pros:**

- Doesn't require prior knowledge of the header's names.
- Can be used to update the header automatically if an existing one is detected.

**Cons:**

- Won't work well if data contains strings. Replacing `if any()` to require all elements to be strings might help, unless data also contains entire rows of strings.