# Delete or remove headers from text files being read in

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove or delete headers of data I am reading in using pandas. One file has a header and the other doesn't but I want to be able to check for headers and then remove it.

So far, I have tried using header=None in the read_csv function

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

def _reader(fname):
    return pd.read_csv(fname, sep="\t", header=None)

folder = Path("C:\\Me\\Project1")
data = pd.concat([
    _reader(txt)
    for txt in folder.glob("*.txt")
])
```

I get the following error:
TypeError: must be str, not int

My two files look like this:

File1.txt

```
ISIN    AVL_QTY
BAD 90000
AAB 8550000
BAD 173688
BAD 360000
BAD 90000
BAD 810000
BAD 900000
BAD 900000
```

File2.txt

```
TEST  543
HELLO 555
STOCK 900
CODE  785
```

Comment: use header=0 and see if that works

Comment: no luck, says KeyError: 0

Comment: There's a skiprows argument that can be passed to reqd_csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need a check if the first line is a header. E.g. you can check if any of the first row's entries begins with a number, as this would not be typical for a column header.
In fact without knowing your thousands of files the right approach for header detection is just guessing - but that's not really the point in your code.

To make use of a header detection, you should go with normal loop instead of a list comprehension, so that you can in each iteration: 1. check for header 2. read the file and append the data to a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in folder.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(f) as fin:
        chk_lst = next(fin).split()
    is_h = not any(v[0].isdecimal() for v in chk_lst)
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+', header=(None, 0)[is_h])], axis=1)

# ISIN  AVL_QTY      0        1
# 0  BAD    90000   TEST  543.775                             
# 1  AAB  8550000  HELLO  555.000                           
# 2  BAD   173688  STOCK  900.000                         
# 3  BAD   360000   CODE  785.000                         
# 4  BAD    90000    NaN      NaN                        
# 5  BAD   810000    NaN      NaN                         
# 6  BAD   900000    NaN      NaN                         
# 7  BAD   900000    NaN      NaN
```

---

Edit:
For concatenating row wise, you can use

```
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=(0, 1)[is_h])], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

#        0        1
# 0    BAD    90000                                     
# 1    AAB  8550000                                      
# 2    BAD   173688                                         
# 3    BAD   360000                                      
# 4    BAD    90000                                        
# 5    BAD   810000                                        
# 6    BAD   900000                                    
# 7    BAD   900000                                    
# 8   TEST      543                                       
# 9  HELLO      555                                      
# 10 STOCK      900                                       
# 11  CODE      785
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. How do I print the last two columns in the next line instead of side by side?

Comment: Generally, this is done by setting `axis=0`. However, in this case I'd fix `header` to `None` and add `skiprows` in dependency of `is_h`.

Comment: Changing to the edit version renders this error: TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not WindowsPath. Removed StringIO works now

Comment: @ravecoder Right, sorry, copy/paste error from my test script, where I don't have your files... Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

`File2.txt` does not have header, right? but in `_reader` you set `header` as `None`.
Add header to File2.txt and see what happens.

Comment: This is just a snippet. In reality I will be reading in thousands of files so I won't be able to dictate if files have a header. But to your point, when I remove headers manually it works fine

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to check if a csv file has a header

using the csv library

```
import csv
with open('example.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    sniffer = csv.Sniffer()
    has_header = sniffer.has_header(csvfile.read(2048))
    csvfile.seek(0)
    # ...
```

[my source](http://%20%20%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/40193509/2327328)

---

or if you know your data, checking if there are any digits in the first row

```
is_header = not any(cell.isdigit() for cell in csv_table[0])
```

[my source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40193471/2327328)

---

or with pandas itself, if you know what the header *might* be called

```
df = (pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=cols)
      [lambda x: np.ones(len(x)).astype(bool)
                 if (x.iloc[0] != cols).all()
                 else np.concatenate([[False], np.ones(len(x)-1).astype(bool)])]
    )
```

[my source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38360744/2327328)

---

and of course if you want to preprocess the files with the command line first, it'll probably be faster....